# adding/deleting items from a list and updating the total

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cart

I'm building something akin to a shopping cart but adding items to a shortlist.

I need to add the item to the cart and then update the cart count and display the added item in a modal window (I'm planning on using the [Reveal plugin by Zurb](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin)).

Thus far, I've got the adding to cart working but I'm not yet able to update the count (without refreshing the page) or display the modal.

http://jsfiddle.net/x7Azn/2/

```
$('a.add-to-shortlist').on('click',function(){  
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('data-href'),
  success: function(data) {     
      verb = data['verb'];
      total_items = data['total_items'];
      alert('item added to shortlist');
  }
});
  // stop event propagation here
 return false;
});
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: So, which part is not working? Do you get the alert? Have you confirmed `total_items` is correct?

Comment: Is your alert going off?  When testing AJAX, I'll typically throw in a success and error callback handler so that I can debug each.  Wouldn't hurt if you could debug and show us whats in the data object you are getting back.

Comment: the alert displays fine and the count is updated (a page refresh shows the cart items have updated). Here is some better info on the data object http://squarebit.co.uk/shortlist/docs/ajax-actions#content

Comment: Have you tried replacing your "#" in the anchor with "javascript:void(0);", and replacing your return false with an e.preventDefault(); such as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: shouldn't need javascript:void(0) but changing return false to e.preventDefault(); seems to be working. How would I now change the text of the a element to read 'remove from list' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text following the e.preventDefault() call, put the following within the function -

```
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).text('remove from list');
```

Comment: hmmm, that works although surely we only want that on success?

Comment: You are correct, I'd just stick the text change into the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.item-count')html(total_items );
```

Comment: you mean $('.item-count').html(total_items); ? I tried that already